# Unable to install slam on Mac OS 10.8.3

Tags: r, macos, slam

I'm having some trouble installing the R package "slam" on my machine. I'm running a Macbook Pro OS 10.8.3 with R Version 3.2.1.

In order to get RTextTools package to work, I require a slam package of version 0.1-30 and above. I've read the documentation and it states that slam v0.1-30 and above (with the exception of 0.1-38) can run on any R version above 2.8.0.

This doesn't seem to be the case however. I've tried everything from 0.1-31 to 0.1-37 and the installation keeps failing with the following message:

> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/slam’
>   * restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/slam’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘/Users/(user)/Downloads/slam_0.1-34.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Can anybody help me please? Is there a way to solve this problem (either install RTextTools or install slam) without upgrading my machine's OS?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't update R?

Comment: Can't update R because I'm trying to stick to OS 10.8.

Comment: Is the macOS 10.8 a limitation due to old Mac hardware? You're running an operating system with an incredible number of actively exploited vulnerabilities. Also, are there no other discrete error messages as to where the compilation failed?

Comment: @hrbrmstr yes, a hardware issue. here's a larger chunk of the response I get from R studio.

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/x86_64'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [slam.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’

Comment: It looks like you don't have a working/complete `gcc` / `gfortran` installation. Where have you downloaded/installed those from?

Comment: @hrbrmstr i've actually never installed/touched those packages before. how should I go about fixing those?

Comment: Have you ever compiled packages that rely on C/C++/fortran source code before? If not, you need to investigate how to do that, but taking into account you're working on a woefully old operating system. I have no idea if [homebrew](http://brew.sh/index.html) will work for you to install what you need. It might be easier to install [virtualbox](virtualbox guest additions), then install an Ubuntu guest OS and install a modern R under it. Though, that's quite a bit of work, too.

Comment: Do you have a working Xcode installation?If not you need to install it.